# Magento SQLSTATE[42S22]

Tags: php, mysql, sql, magento, debugging

I am just getting this error... 
Please help me out fixing this error!

www.sp-power.com

```
Error in file: "/home/sppower6/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/sql/eav_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.7.10-0.7.11.php" - SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'is_filterable' in 'field list'

Trace:
#0 /home/sppower6/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(645): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')
#1 home/sppower6/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb('upgrade', '0.7.10', '1.6.0.1')
#2  /home/sppower6/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(320): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_upgradeResourceDb('0.7.10', '1.6.0.1')
#3 /home/sppower6/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(235): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyUpdates()
#4 /home/sppower6/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(428): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()
#5 /home/sppower6/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#6 /home/sppower6/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#7 /home/sppower6/public_html/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#8 {main}
```

Comment: add some background talk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the column is_filterable in the setup script to the proper entity, such as product, category or order:

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'is_filterable', array(
  'type'              => 'int',
  'backend'           => '',
  'frontend'          => '',
  'label'             => 'Is Filterable',
  'input'             => 'boolean',
  'source'            => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean',
  'class'             => '',
  'global'            => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
  'visible'           => true,
  'required'          => false,
  'user_defined'      => false,
  'default'           => '',
  'searchable'        => false,
  'filterable'        => false,
  'comparable'        => false,
  'visible_on_front'  => false,
  'unique'            => false,
  'group'             => 'Any Group'
));

$installer->endSetup();
```